# Windows Service C# Issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-services

I am working on this c# code which is windows based, the requirement now is to convert this functionality into windows service. I followed following link from msdn for my conversion approach:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Getting rid of all form functions, I kept my logic intact which transfers access file and parses it to text format, although the service seems to be running but it's not working same way as win app.

Here's windows service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

/** Using Config File for Directories **/
using System.Configuration;

//====Read From Access namespace===============
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
//using System.IO;
//=============================================

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;

using System.Configuration.Install;

namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples
{

  // Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface Copytask
    {
        [OperationContract]
         void copyej();

    }

    public class CopyejService : Copytask
    {
        // Implement the Copy EJ methods.

        public void copyej()
        {
            // Functionality Derivation


            string target_dir_file =   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir_File"];

            string target_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir"];

            string text_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TextDir"];

            string file_name = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName"];

            string source_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir_File"];


            // Check if Target Directory Exists            
            DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(target_dir);

            if (!theFolder.Exists)
            {
                theFolder.Create();
            }

            /*
            if (!File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {
               // MessageBox.Show("Function Exited");
                return;
            }*/

            // Delet if EJ file exists
            if (File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {

                File.Delete(target_dir_file);
            }


            // Copy the EJ file in Target Directory
            File.Copy(source_dir_file, target_dir_file);


            //=============Extract contents in Access and save it as Text File Format==========================================
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test\TestEJFolder\BWC_Ejournal.mdb";           

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string sql    = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            string dt     = "SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM Events";
            string count = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Events";


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(dt, conn1);
            conn1.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(count, conn2);
            conn2.Open();   

            string time_stmp = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

            string s_path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + "Session"+ "_" + file_name;


            FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(source_dir_file);

            string fname = "File Name: \"" + oFileInfo.Name + "|" + " ";
            string fsize = "File total Size: " + oFileInfo.Length.ToString() + "|" + " ";
            string fdts = "Date and Time File Created: " + oFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString() + "|" + " ";


            Int32 r_count = (Int32)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();    
            StreamWriter sp = File.CreateText(s_path);    
            sp.WriteLine(fname + fsize + fdts + "Record Count " + r_count);    
            sp.Close();    

            conn1.Close();
            conn2.Close();

            string path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + file_name;

            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);

            const string format = "{0,-22} {1,-4} {2,-4} {3,-4} {4,-20} {5,-22}";



            string line;
            while (reader.Read())
            {   
                line = string.Format(format, reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").Trim(),
                    reader.GetInt32(0).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(1).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(2).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(3).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(4).ToString().Trim());

                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();

            //====End Of Extract Access contents and save it as Text Format=========================================================

        }

    }


    public class CopyEJWindowsService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public CopyEJWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "CopyEJWindowsService";
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new CopyEJWindowsService());
        }

      // Start the Windows service.
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {
          if (serviceHost != null)
          {
              serviceHost.Close();
          }

          // Create a ServiceHost for the CopyEJService type and 
          // provide the base address.
          serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CopyejService));  

          // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
          // listening for messages.
          serviceHost.Open();
      }



      protected override void OnStop()
      {
          if (serviceHost != null)
          {
              serviceHost.Close();
              serviceHost = null;
          }
      }
    }

    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "CopyEJWindowsService";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

=======================================================================

## Here's windows application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;



/** Using Config File for Directories **/
using System.Configuration;



//====Read From Access namespace===============
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
//using System.IO;
//=============================================

namespace CopyEJTask
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string log;
        int ctr;
        public Form1()
        {              

            InitializeComponent();

            //timer1.Interval = Int32.Parse(txtTimer.Text);
            this.Opacity = 0;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ctr = 0;

            string target_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir"];

            textBox3.Text = ctr.ToString();

            DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(target_dir);

            if (!theFolder.Exists)
            {
                theFolder.Create();
            }


            //textBox1.Text = @"C:\Test\TestEJFolder";
            textBox1.Text = target_dir;



        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            success();
        }


        private void success()
        {
            //if (!theFolder.Exists)
            //{
            //    theFolder.Create();
            // }
            timer1.Stop();

            timerFileExist.Start();
            timerCopyEJ.Start();

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);




           // timer1.Start();

            //MessageBox.Show("File Copied");

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void manageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.Opacity=100;
            this.WindowState=FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void hideToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 100;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void menuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 0;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void manageToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Opacity = 100;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }

        private void timerFileExist_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string target_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir_File"];


            if (File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {

                File.Delete(target_dir_file);
            }

            timerFileExist.Stop();
        }

        private void timerCopyEJ_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string source_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir_File"];

            string target_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir_File"];

            File.Copy(source_dir_file, target_dir_file); // Update For Pavneet

            ctr = ctr + 1;

            textBox3.Text = ctr.ToString();

            log = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = log;



            timer1.Start();
            timerCopyEJ.Stop();
            timerExtractMDB.Start();
        }

        private void timerExtractMDB_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            string target_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TargetDir_File"];

            if (!File.Exists(target_dir_file))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Function Exited");
                return;
            }




            //=============Extract contents in Access and save it as Text File Format==========================================
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test\TestEJFolder\BWC_Ejournal.mdb";           

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string sql    = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            string dt     = "SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM Events";
            string count = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Events";


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(dt, conn1);
            conn1.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(count, conn2);
            conn2.Open();


            string text_dir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TextDir"];

            string file_name = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName"];

            string source_dir_file = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SourceDir_File"];

            string time_stmp = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

            string s_path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + "Session"+ "_" + file_name;


            FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(source_dir_file);

            string fname = "File Name: \"" + oFileInfo.Name + "|" + " ";
            string fsize = "File total Size: " + oFileInfo.Length.ToString() + "|" + " ";
            string fdts = "Date and Time File Created: " + oFileInfo.CreationTime.ToString() + "|" + " ";




            Int32 r_count = (Int32)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

            StreamWriter sp = File.CreateText(s_path);

            sp.WriteLine(fname + fsize + fdts + "Record Count " + r_count);

            sp.Close();


            conn1.Close();
            conn2.Close();

            string path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + file_name;

            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);

            const string format = "{0,-22} {1,-4} {2,-4} {3,-4} {4,-20} {5,-22}";



            string line;
            while (reader.Read())
            {



                line = string.Format(format, reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").Trim(),
                    reader.GetInt32(0).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(1).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetInt32(2).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(3).ToString().Trim(),
                   reader.GetString(4).ToString().Trim());

                sw.WriteLine(line);




            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();

            //====End Of Extract Access contents and save it as Text Format=========================================================



            timerExtractMDB.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Also any ideas on how to log each event of service would be helpful.

Comment: For logging you can use log4net. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Ok, so it is not working the same.  Can you provide some more details?  What is it doing that it didn't do before, or not doing that it did do?

Comment: The core functionality is not working, it seems the main function which is copyej() is not getting kicked off, ideally it should move the access file and then translate data to a text file and few other things as per the mentioned code. So as per the logic coded in function copyej() : it should move the .mdb file from mentioned location , then I create intermediate session file as per information in mdb file thereafter finally reading the data in text format and creating a text file.   All of this works as exactly in winform code, services are not working.

Comment: Nothing is calling `copyej()` so of course it's not getting "kicked off".

Comment: serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CopyejService)); should be calling this function which is Onstart function

Comment: I'm wondering - as I'm reading this very often lately - why people write things like `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName"]` instead of `Properties.Settings.Default.FileName`. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a web service to be hosted. All you need is a timer in windows service and execute your task everytime timer is elapsed. Windows Service code looks like below:

```
private System.Timers.Timer serviceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    InitTimer();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    serviceTimer.Stop();
}

private void InitTimer()
{
    serviceTimer.Start();
    serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
    serviceTimer.Interval = 5000;
    serviceTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnServiceTimerElapsed);
}

public void OnServiceTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    serviceTimer.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        copyej();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
                 //Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        serviceTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi venu .. I am getting error "The name copyej() does not exist in current context" .. is this because function is defined in separate class ?

Comment: yes..you just copy your copyej() function in the same service class. It should work fine.